# HTML file won't connect to CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

Hey guys so I'm just creating a simple webpage for class but for some reason my html file won't connect to my css file, it is in the same folder and everything. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!--<style>
        body {
            background-image: url('gold.jpg');
            background-repeat: repeat;
        }
    </style>-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body class="loggedin">
            <div class = "tab-content">
                <h1>Role: Admin</h1>
                <li><a href="#">Manage User Accounts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Assign Roles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help Desk</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS

```
body {
        background:
                url(gold.jpg) center repeat;
     }
#tablist{
padding: 3px 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-top: 0.1em;
font: bold 12px Verdana;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#tablist li{
list-style: none;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
}

#tablist li a{
text-decoration: none;
padding: 3px 0.5em;
margin-right: 3px;
border: 1px solid #778;
border-bottom: none;
background: white;
}
```

Comment: Is your css `style.css` file in the same directory as your html file ?

Comment: Tip: open up the network panel of DevTools, and look around... Also read https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging

Comment: <title> tag is made to put your file's title (Not to place links). Put your <link> out of elsewhere in <head> but out from <title>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should structure your HTML correctly. Starting by removing your CSS file from the Title since it won't work there.

Second, Check your folder structure and make sure you are following the right path to your CSS file.

Then if you are using VS code. You could just click `!` (exclamation mark)  and you get to pick a prebuilt HTML page that will get you started with the right structure.

Here is an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="testing">Hello world</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be multiple reasons:

1. Your "link" tag shouldn't go inside the "title" tag
2. Make sure your css file is in the same directory as the html one, and check if the file name is the same.
3. Check your css file

Edit: Just checked and you have no elements with such Id, make sure you can see the changes made by the css file.
Also check the developer console, it helps a lot in debugging.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with it:

1. The link tag should not go in the title tag. Keep them seperate, but within the head.
2. Type attribute in the link tAG is not neccesary. Try to keep things simple.
3. Check your CSS file name. It may be different.

Here is your corrected code:

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Your Title </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine in your code. There is just a little mistake to do some change and enjoy.
1)Remove the link(CSS) from the title.
2) Your class name is **tab-content** but you write it this **tablist** in CSS file.
3) class is represented by a dot(.) and id is represented by hash(#)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you put hashes on purpose to make your css code not generating the desired output so i did clean up a bit of your code.

As others already said `<title></title>` expects and accepts only plain text so your link becomes invalid and shows up as such in your browser tab.

Hashes are for Ids and . for classes so i did delete these since there are no Ids configured in your HTML file. When your .css file already sets a background-image you dont need to code it twice in HTML. The code looks cleaner this way and might prevent future errors.

Have a nice day :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>plain text</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="so1.css"/>

</head>
<body class="loggedin">
<div class="tab-content">
<h1>Role: Admin</h1>
<li><a href="#">Manage User Accounts</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Assign Role</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Help Desk</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
        background: url(gold.jpg) center repeat;
     }
div {
padding: 3px 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-top: 0.1em;
font: bold 12px Verdana;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

li{
list-style: none;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
}

li a{
text-decoration: none;
padding: 3px 0.5em;
margin-right: 3px;
border: 1px solid #778;
border-bottom: none;
background: white;
}
```